# What does the "or" symbol mean as in "$ d\mid a$"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

What does the "or" symbol mean as in the following post:

[How to prove $\gcd(a,\gcd(b, c)) = \gcd(\gcd(a, b), c)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105741/how-to-prove-gcda-gcdb-c-gcd-gcda-b-c)

In particular, the symbol is used in the above linked post in the following definition of $\gcd(a, b)$:

> Given integers $a$ and $b$, there is one and only one number $d$ with the following properties.
>
> 1. $d \geq 0$
> 2. $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$
> 3. $e\mid a$ and $e\mid b$ implies $e\mid d$.

Comment: It is not an "or" symbol, it is a vertical bar. Saying it is an "or" symbol is already applying a (here inappropriate) interpretation to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, you write $a|b$ to mean that $a$ divides $b$, or equivalently, that there is an integer $m$ such that $b=ma$.

See the article *[Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor)* on Wikipedia, and also *[Vertical bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Mathematics)* for other uses of this symbol.

Answer (score 2):

you mean $d|a$. It is not 'or' symbol. It means d divides a.

Comment: did you mean divides absoulutely with remainder 0.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit Yes, that's the meaning of "divides" here.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut could you please post the link to the citiation if you knew one. This is the first time i come a symbol which has this type of meaning.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor